# using getchar() to read all input

Tags: c, string

#### Input:

```
hi my name is john
how are you
thanks.
```

#### Desired Output:

```
himynameisjohnhowareyouthanks
```

#### My code is:

```
int main(void){
    {
        char *strptr = ""; 
        int i = 0;

        while(EOF){

            while(islower(getchar())==true){
                strcat(strptr,tolower(getchar()));
            }
            printf("%s",strptr); 
        }              
    }  
}
```

How can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: You can't just write `EOF` as a `while` condition. You need to test your read character against `EOF`. And don't forget to reserve enough memory. `strcat`ing stuff to your string constant should cause a segfault.

Comment: shouldn't that be `while(!EOF){` ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have some issues in your code, specifically with `while(EOF)` part. Also, your code can be simpler with a little additional effort.

Check the below code for reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input = 0;

    while (( input = getchar()) != EOF)   //read untill EOF
    {
        if (islower(input ))           //print only lower case alphabetic character  
            putchar(input);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Just in case you want also to *convert* the UPPERCASE alphabates to lowercase and print, have a look at [`tolower()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower).

Comment: The input also is made up of multiple lines. It looks like Ozan is stripping all non alpha characters.

Comment: @BillLynch OOps, q got edited.

Comment: Yep. The original question didn't have the input in a code block, so the newlines were ignored by markdown.

Comment: yep. it's the part which i couldn't. I have to read all the lines and keep in an string @BillLynch

Comment: char *string;
    char c;
   
    string = "";
    c = "";   
 --------------------------------   
    do{
       c = getchar();
      
       if(c==EOF)
            break;
       if (c != '.')             
   strcat(string,c);

    }while(EOF);

    printf("\n%s",string);
} ----------------------
@SouravGhosh   i tried this but i coudnt get that wht strcat isn' working.

Comment: @ozan either use an array or allocate memory to the pointer. I'm off for the day. Try this and let me know. We'll discuss if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Write this way

```
int c;
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
   if(islower(c)==true)
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

It will print all the lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

first, make a variable that will get the character using `getchar()`, then
substitute the `getchar()`s with the variable.
`int v = getchar()`
Then you will surely get proper output.
   `